# Moving an element inside canvas with Leap Motion Leap.Js - How to save a state?

Tags: javascript, canvas, leap-motion, sigma.js

I'm trying to make LEAP motion to zoom in and out of a Canvas element and it works fine.

Right now when you put your hand in the active zone and move vertically or horizontally, the object moves accordingly. Fine.

When you put your hand towards the screen, the element decreases in size, when you pull it towards yourself, it increases in size. Also good.

The problems start when you want to move your hand away from the zone.

The element follows you to the extreme, which means it becomes very big (if you pull your hand back to yourself). I managed to implement a control where if I put away some fingers (e.g. point with a finger to a screen – PIN it), then the image freezes. Good.

Now, the problem and the question: how to make it that when I put my hand back in the control zone, the element starts from the same position where I left it? I've been struggling with it all night, and it was difficult and I didn't manage. So if you manage to do it, at least I owe you a beer :)

Here's the code (s is my canvas element, cameras[0] has the x,y properties, .ratio is the depth):

```
        var defaultRatio = s.cameras[0].ratio;
        var firstValidFrame = null;
        var started = null;
        var controller = new Leap.Controller({enableGestures: true});
        controller.loop(function(frame) {
            if(frame.hands.length > 0)
            {
                if (!firstValidFrame && frame.valid) firstValidFrame = frame;
                var hand = frame.hands[0];
                var position = hand.stabilizedPalmPosition;
                var fingers = hand.fingers;
                var center = hand.sphereCenter;

                if (position[2] < 60) {
                    started = 1;
                }

                if (fingers.length > 2 && started) {
                    s.cameras[0].x =  - position[0]*2;
                    s.cameras[0].y = position[1]*2-360;
                    s.cameras[0].ratio = defaultRatio - (position[2]*2/360);

                }
            }
        });
```

I'm using it with Leap.Js library in my Node.Js app on Sigma.Js graph visualization in case you're interested...

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Make the user move their hand to back to the same spot where the moving element was "dropped" before starting to move it again.
2. Move the element relative to the hand position. In other words, when you put your hand back into the active zone, save that position and as the hand moves, move the element by the same relative amount.